# Pass class object to two objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class `Database`. In my class `A` I create a new object from the database and two objects of class `B`. Now I want to access the database object from both class `B` objects. I tried passing the object as pointer and reference but when I print the adress it's always different.

Class A.h:

```
Database database; 
B b1; 
B b2;
```

Class A.cpp:

```
b1.setDatabase(database); 
b2.setDatabase(database);

b1.insert("A"); 
b2.insert("B");
b1.insert("C");
b2.insert("D");
```

Class B.h

```
Database database;
```

Class B.cpp

```
void setDatabase(Database& database) { 
  this->database = database; 
}

void insert(std::string name) { 
  database.dataMap.insert({ name, 10 }); 

  std::cout << database.dataMap.size() << std::endl; 
}
```

Class Database.h

```
std::map<std::string, int> dataMap;
```

The output should be 
1
2
3
4

But it is

1
1
2
2

So I think it's not the same object

Comment: `B` needs to store a pointer or reference to `Database` in order to do this.  What does you `B` look like?

Comment: Looking at the code you show your `B` stores `Database` as a copy. So clearly when you modify one of the databases you do nothing to the other or the one you started with.

Comment: I changed the code to store a pointer object. The code compiles but if I run the program it closes immediately.

Comment: @MartinM. We'd need a [mre] in order to help with that.  That said, since you already have an answer here, you would need to ask a new question about that.

Comment: The above code is my full short example.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a reference. What you are doing is copying yout Database. You need to copy the address (pointer):

Class B.h

```
class B
{
private:
  Database* database; //Pointer to Database instead of actual Database object

public:
  void setDatabase(Database* database) //Pass pointer(*) instead of reference(&)
  { 
    this->database = database; // Assign pointer instead of calling the implicit copy constructor
  }

  void insert(string name) { 
    database->dataMap.insert({ name, 10 }); //Dereferencing and member access(->) instead of member access only(.)

    cout << database->dataMap.size() << endl;
  }

}
```

Class A.h:

```
  Database database; 
  B b1; 
  B b2;
```

Class a.cpp:

```
b1.setDatabase(&database); 
b2.setDatabase(&database);

b1.insert("A"); 
b2.insert("B");
b1.insert("C");
b2.insert("D");
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/84evCd)

Comment: If I change the code to yours I can't insert the values to the map.

Comment: You need to use the address operator(&) like this: `setDatabase(&database)` in your main.

Comment: Yes. But I mean the ``database->dataMap.insert()`` isn't working

Comment: My fault. it's called `db` now, so 'db->dataMap.insert()' of course.

Comment: The db was not the problem. It isn't working anyway.

Comment: Yeah, fixed that i guess. Thanks hegel5000

Comment: @MartinM. what is not working? What is the error you get?

Comment: The console is displaying no error. But visual studio shows the following error: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000019

Comment: But here you are using a struct instead of class. And my classes are placed in different files.

Comment: @MartinM. struct and class are the same, and placing the class in different files should not change a thing. I'll edit so it's a class anyway if that helps.